# two errors while compiling meshlab and vcglib

Tags: c++

I got one problem during compiling the Meshlab_mini (2020.12 version) with Vcglib (2020.12 version) with visual studio 2019 and qt 5.15.2.

The problem is below

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
> (active)  E0135   class "vcg::tri::Append<vcgTriMesh, vcgTriMesh>" has no
> member
> "MeshAppendConst" meshlab-common  E:\meshlab-master\src\common\ml_document\cmesh.cpp  38
>
> Error (active)    E0135   class "vcg::tri::Append<vcgTriMesh, vcgTriMesh>"
> has no member
> "MeshCopyConst"   meshlab-common  E:\LaSys\HumanFace\meshlab-master\src\common\ml_document\cmesh.cpp  59

Sure, there are no member functions named red above in the file of `cmesh.cpp`.

Could you help out of here? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] I got the sourcecode by the Code -> Download ZIP method, and then compiled the project with the error above. By the great help from Alessandro Muntonialessandro.muntoni@isti.cnr.it, i.e., the 'git clone --recursive github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab' method, then the compilation of the source code of the Meshlab and the Vcglib is perfectly solved. Many thanks to Alessandro Muntonialessandro.muntoni@isti.cnr.it.